# Specify that a TypeVar supports the "-" operator among its values

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

Basically, I want to say that I have a type `T` which has a `T.__sub__(self, other: T) -> T` defined. I can currently make it typecheck as if it has a `T.__sub__(self, other: Any) -> Any` defined, but only works if `T` is a class I defined myself.

---

I'm trying to type the following class

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic
from dataclasses import dataclass
T = TypeVar('T')
@dataclass
class Consumption(Generic[T]):
    first: T
    second: T
    def difference(self) -> T:
        return self.second - self.first
```

However, my LSP (`pyright`) complains that "`Operator "-" not supported for types "T@Consumption" and "T@Consumption"`".

I've inspired myself in the `typing` library and `SupportsAbs` implementation to try and circumvent this in the following way

```py
from typing import TypeVar, Generic, Protocol
from dataclasses import dataclass
from abc import abstractmethod

E = TypeVar('E')
class SupportsSub(Generic[E], Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def __sub__(self, other: E) -> E: pass
```

With this class, I can express that the `difference` method is well-typed in the following way

```py
T = TypeVar('T')
@dataclass
class Consumption(Generic[T]):
    first: T
    second: SupportsSub[T]
    def difference(self) -> T:
        return self.second - self.first
```

but I lose the ability to say that `second` is actually also of type `T`. I've tried to define `T` such that it supports being subtracted with itself, but "`TypeVar bound type cannot be generic`".

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=SupportsSub["T"])
```

I can just exclude the generic in `SupportsSub` to make it type-check, but then it also allows other methods which are not well-typed

```py
T = TypeVar('T', bound=SupportsSub)
def shouldnt_type(a: T, b: int) -> int:
    return a - b
```

Another problem with this approach is that I can't have a `Consumption[float]`, since `float` doesn't inherit from `SupportsSub`. Therefore, `pyright` will complain about the following.

```py
class Other:
    water: Consumption[float]
```

I've had similar problems with `pyright` for example warning me that `PySide.QtCore.QDate` doesn't support the `<` operator, when in fact it does. Is it currently possible to express this with Python's typing?

Comment: Side-note: Your `SupportsSub` is actually specifying that it supports *addition*, not subtraction. Presumably you wanted the `@abstractmethod` to be `__sub__`, not `__add__`.

Comment: Oh, you're right, that's a silly mistake.

Comment: Another obvious issue: `def SupportsSub...` should be `class SupportsSub...`.

Comment: Indeed, fixed it. Thanks

Comment: I don't think you want `@abstractmethod` on your Protocol. Either use ABC or Protocol, but not both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [`typing.Self`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Self). That way you can specify that the value being subtracted must be the same type as `self`.

```
from typing import Protocol, TypeVar, Self, Generic
from dataclasses import dataclass
E = TypeVar('E')

class SupportsSub(Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def __sub__(self, other: Self) -> Self: pass

T = TypeVar('T', bound=SupportsSub)

@dataclass
class Consumption(Generic[T]):
    first: T
    second: T
    def difference(self) -> T:
        return self.second - self.first
    
def shouldnt_type(a: T, b: int) -> T:
    return a - b # doesn't type
```

Comment: not sure you want `@abstractmethod` in a Protocol

Comment: @Anentropic it doesn't matter afaik. Pylance might else complain that the function doesn't return a `Self` instance. I've just kept the code as close as possible as OP posted it.

Comment: I think it's just spurious, mypy is happy without it: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=6ead32a47aa5a6fb4d6f8548669b8359

Comment: I didn't know about typing.Self, thanks! However, pyright still rejects Consumption[float] nevertheless. This seems to be specific to pyright, since mypy seems to accept it: https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=306d7aaf0b3d80aa406689eb27ead302

Comment: It seems like `pyright` doesn't accept it since `__sub__` doesn't specify that the second argument is positional only. That would be `__sub__(self, other: Self, /) -> Self`. I asked about it in `pyright`'s repo, and that's what they answered: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/discussions/5641

Answer (score 1):

Robin gives the answer for strictly identical types, I just wanted to add on a solution for when the types differ, but it's okay to use them together for subtraction (with the assumption that subtraction is implemented on the left-hand side, and the result is the same type as the left-hand side).

In that case, your generics need to know about two types, the covariant type of the left-hand side, and the contravariant type of the right-hand side. You'd define `SupportsSub` as:

```
E = TypeVar("E", covariant=True)
F = TypeVar("F", contravariant=True)
class SupportsSub(Generic[E, F], Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def __sub__(self: E, other: F) -> E: pass
```

allowing it to be explicitly generic in the type of both sides.

You then define your dataclass with:

```
T = TypeVar("T")
U = TypeVar("U")
@dataclass
class Consumption(Generic[T, U]):
     first: U
     second: SupportsSub[T, U]  # Binds T and U together so their intercompatibility is known
     def difference(self) -> T:  # Returned T type is same as second's T type, so it should effectively be the concrete type of second (or a subclass)
         return self.second - self.first
```

It can be done with fewer `TypeVar`s and less complexity using `typing.Self`:

```
E = TypeVar("E", contravariant=True)  # Only need generic for the right-hand side
class SupportsSub(Generic[E], Protocol):
    @abstractmethod
    def __sub__(self, other: E) -> Self: pass

T = TypeVar("T")
@dataclass
class Consumption(Generic[T]):
    first: T
    second: SupportsSub[T]
    def difference(self) -> SupportsSub[T]:  # Can't annotate specific return type based on realized type of second AFAICT
        return self.second - self.first
```

but with `difference` annotated as returning `SupportsSub[T]`, I don't believe you could rely on any other features of the real type of `second` with casting to silence the type-checker, where the two `TypeVar` solution should preserve the full features of the underlying type.

Comment: `(Generic[E, F], Protocol)` can be reduced to `Protocol[E, F]` - extra `Generic` is not necessary for protocols. And this will result in spurious errors like "cannot infer type argument" if `Consumption` is used wrongly (e.g. `Consumption('', 0)`) - while it is a `mypy` error as expected, it probably isn't helpful enough on its own and should be documented in `Consumption` docstring.

Comment: Also I'm not sure that `mypy` doesn't get angry on this - covariant type vars cannot be used in arguments, and contravariant - as a return type.

Comment: Oh, and pyright does point this out indeed, so you've just discovered a `mypy` bug.